# SQL Sub queries, inner join on max value to bring back max records only

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a table with service ticket dispatch data. Each dispatch has its own ID. For any given service ticket, a service technician can have several dispatch IDs if it takes him several trips to solve the problem. I'm interested at any given time at only looking at the status of the LATEST dispatch ID record. In Access, I admittedly was spoon fed because all I had to do was make a query that grouped on Service_Ticket_Id and brought back the max dispatch_ID. I then connected that query back to the original dispatch table with an inner join on dispatch_ID and that pulled back only the latest dispatch records. However, I'm now being forced to do this in one query. The below is obviously screwed up. I also need to connect this overall result to another table showing tech name etc., although this isn't absolutely crucial.

```
SELECT 
    Max(dbo_SV_Service_Ticket_Dispatch.Dispatch_Id) AS MaxOfDispatch_Id,           
    dbo_SV_Service_Ticket_Dispatch.Service_Ticket_Id
FROM 
    dbo_SV_Service_Ticket_Dispatch
GROUP BY 
    dbo_SV_Service_Ticket_Dispatch.Service_Ticket_Id
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         dbo_SV_Ticket_Dispatch.Dispatch_Time  
     FROM
         dbo_SV_Service_Ticket_Dispatch) ON dbo_SV_Service_Ticket_Dispatch.Dispatch_Id = MaxofDispatch_ID
```

Comment: You should replace the `group by` to the end of the query

Comment: I've updated my answer with an additional example.

Comment: Using `Max` is not great, instead use analytical/windowing functions or a `TOP` clause inside an `OUTER APPLY`. Then you can dispense with reliance on an `Id` that *might* not represent time order with 100% reliability, or on a `DateTime` that could be non-unique.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, by using sub queries or using CTE or Temporary tables.BTW for simplicity try the following.

```
SELECT Max(Dispatch_Id) AS MaxOfDispatch_Id,Service_Ticket_Id into #t
FROM dbo_SV_Service_Ticket_Dispatch 
GROUP BY Service_Ticket_Id

SELECT Dispatch_Time from 
dbo_SV_Service_Ticket_Dispatch where Dispatch_Id= (select MaxOfDispatch_Id from #t)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the details of the dispatch based on max dispatch_id per service_ticket_id, you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT MAX(dm.dispatch_Id) AS maxDispatchId, dm.Service_Ticket_Id
   FROM dbo_SV_Service_Ticket_Dispatch dm
   GROUP BY Service_Ticket_Id) m
INNER JOIN dbo_SV_Service_Ticket_Dispatch d ON d.dispatch_id = m.dispatch_id
```

**UPDATE**

To get the details from the ticket table, just join it on the ticket id:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT MAX(dm.dispatch_Id) AS maxDispatchId, dm.Service_Ticket_Id
   FROM dbo_SV_Service_Ticket_Dispatch dm
   GROUP BY Service_Ticket_Id) m
INNER JOIN dbo_SV_Service_Ticket_Dispatch d ON d.dispatch_id = m.dispatch_id
INNER JOIN dbo_SV_Service_Ticket t ON t.Service_Ticket_Id = m.Service_Ticket_Id
```